# Java Error, required: char[] found char

Tags: java, arrays, character

I have made a character array in Java,

`char[] letterGrade = { 'A','B','C','D','F'};`

and am trying to reference the elements like this,

```
letterGrade[0]
```

I am getting an error that says incompatible types

required: 
char[]

found: char

I've done this elsewhere in the code with an array of doubles and it worked fine.  Why doesn't it work with a character array?

Thanks!

**update from your comment**

```
public static void method()
{
    double totalEarnedPoints = 1;
    double totalPossiblePoints = 1;

    double gradePer = 0.0;
    gradePer = (totalEarnedPoints / totalPossiblePoints);
    char[] letterGrade = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','F'};
    if (gradePer >= gradeScale[0])
    {
        letterGrade = char letterGrade(0);
    }
    else if (calcPercent >= gradeCutoffs[1] && calcPercent < gradeCutoffs[0])
    {
        letterGrade= char letterGrade(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: char[] letterGrade = { 'A','B','C','D','F'};
     System.out.println(letterGrade[0]);

It worked for me, what is the context you have used?

Comment: Please describe, where are you using it? can you give that part of code?

Comment: Yes, I got that to work too.  I was trying to get it to return an element of my array as the result of an if else statement.  I'm not sure I like using the System print line as a result for an if else statement that has 5 possible answers - grades A-F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted sample works if your target variable is of type char, so I assume that you are doing something wrong in the assignment. Maybe you are calling a function which requires a `char[]` in wich case you should use `funct(letterGrade)` without the `[0]`.

If your problem persists you should post a bit more code.

**Update**

I fixed your code to make it compile. of course I don't know what it is supposed to be so I had to make some assumptions, but you should see how the syntax is supposed to be.

```
public static void method()
{
    double totalEarnedPoints = 1;
    double totalPossiblePoints = 1;
    double gradeScale[] = {1, 2, 3};
    double gradeCutoffs[] = {1, 2, 3};
    double gradePer = 0.0;
    char letter;
    double calcPercent = 1;

    gradePer = (totalEarnedPoints / totalPossiblePoints);
    char[] letterGrade = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','F'};
    if (gradePer >= gradeScale[0])
    {
        letter = letterGrade[0];
    }
    else if (calcPercent >= gradeCutoffs[1] && calcPercent < gradeCutoffs[0])
    {
        letter = letterGrade[1];
    }
    else
        letter = 'F';

    System.out.println("Grade:"+letter);
}
```

Comment: I've gotten it to work by just referencing the actual letter with the 'System.out.println' but it's also printing 10 characters of letters, numbers, symbols -- looks completely unrelated to the lines of code I'm trying, and do, print to screen?

Comment: `public void method    {
double gradePer= 0.0;
gradePer= (totalEarnedPoints / totalPossiblePoints);
char[] letterGrade = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','F'};
    
if (gradePer >= gradeScale[0])
{
letterGrade= char letterGrade(0);
}
else if (calcPercent >= gradeCutoffs[1] && calcPercent < gradeCutoffs[0])
{
letterGrade= char letterGrade(1);
}`

Comment: I fixed your code and reposted the original version to your question and the compilable version to my answer, so you can compare them. When posting code samples, don't do it in the comment, as it looks horrible. Just edit it into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm trying to implement it with an if statement,

```
char[] letterGrade = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','F'}; 
if (calcPercent >= gradeCutoffs[0]) { 
      letterGrade = letterGrade[0];
}
```

If you are doing so.
Since letterGrade is of type `char[]`, you can't assign it with only char. `L.H.S.` value must be a char.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:
    char[] letterGrade = { 'A','B','C','D','F'};
    System.out.println(letterGrade[0]);
It outputs A

So I suspect it is what you are assigning it to.
Perhaps somewhere you have:
    letterGrade = letterGrade[A]

Comment: I'm trying to implement it with an if statement, char[] letterGrade = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','F'};

           if (calcPercent >= gradeCutoffs[0])
         {
           letterGrade = letterGrade[0];

Answer (score 0):

```
required: char[]

found: char
```

this type of error occurs , if you are assigning a char in char[] datatype.

ex:

```
char[] ch = letterGrade[0];
```